# Search partial data in multiple fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, flask-mongoengine

I performed several tests, I read the MongoDB material a lot to try to find a solution to the problem below:

I have a collection of more than 200GB and I need to search for partial data in some fields, but I didn't get good results. I performed the search using Regex, created Text index among other options, but I didn't get good results.

I would like to consult documents from some fields with partial information informed by the user, for example:

select * from emp where field_name like '% information information2%'

I tried:

```js
db.emp.find ({field_name: / information informacao2 /})

db.emp.find ({$ text: {$ search: "\" informacao informacao2 \ ""})

db.emp.find ({"field_name": {"$ regex": "\" information information2 \ "", "$ options": 'i'}}
```

However, the performance is terrible and does not obtain the data that the user would like to search.

Is there an approach where I can get performance queries and partial data?

The idea is to search for a partial string and search for that information in several fields, but that has an excellent performance.

For example:

```sql
Select *
From emp
Where field_name1 like '% INFO1 INFO2% or field_name2 like'% INFO1 INFO2% '
```

Thanks

Comment: The best solution to replacing like queries is to use MongoDB Atlas Search. It's much faster. Are you using AtlaS?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I'm not using Atlas Search.